# How to interact with Amazon's IoT programmable button's LED light

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, button, lambda, iot

I'm using node.js to create a Lambda function in Amazon Web Services that an IoT button invokes when pressed. The IoT button has a small LED that lights up green if the function was executed successfully and red if there was an error. I'm wondering if there's any way to control the LED more than that? I know it flashes white during the configuration process. I've read through quite a bit of documentation and can't find anything on controlling the LED. Does anyone here know much about it or have suggestions on how to tell the button to change the color, brightness or duration of its LED?

I think it's going to be done with an object sent through Lambda's callback function but I have no idea what format the object needs to be in for it to make sense to the IoT button.

```
callback(Error error, Object success)
```

I might add that I do have everything up and working - I don't need help setting up my button. I also know what the button sends Lambda when it's pressed:

```
{ 
  "serialNumber": "0000000000000000",
  "batteryVoltage": "xxmV",
  "clickType": "SINGLE" | "DOUBLE" | "LONG"
}
```

Edit:

So I found where someone [dumped the firmware](https://github.com/dekuNukem/Amazon_Dash_Button/blob/master/firmware%20dump/Cottonelle_%20stringified.txt) for one of the non-programmable dash buttons and I found this:

```
Usage: led <r> <g> <b>
Usage: led <mode> <r> <g> <b>
    Modes: 'b'==blink; 'f'==fade
Illuminating LED with RGB(%x,%x,%x) color=%8x
```

I don't know what to do with it yet though...

Answer (score 0):

As per AWS IOT APIs, there is something called [Device Shadows](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-thing-shadows.html) using which the state of the thing(IOT button in this case) can be set. But I think that's more generic concept, personally I was not able to do so. I tried long back using the IOT prototype button way before its official launch. That time only one way communication was possible from the Button to the IOT gateway and customization of LED light color or sequence was not possible.

Follow [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-the-aws-iot-button-enterprise-program/) for details on setting up IOT Button.

Comment: The Device Shadow is the payload information the device sends to (in my case) the lambda function, it looks like this:

    {
     "serialNumber": "0000000000000000",
     "batteryVoltage": "xxmV",
     "clickType": "SINGLE" | "DOUBLE" | "LONG"
    }
What I would like to know is what to send back.

Comment: refer [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/using-thing-shadows.html) `{
    "state": {
        "desired" : {
            "color" : { "r" : 10 },
            "engine" : "ON"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks, I think what the device shadow is doing is saving a small amount of information to the device so you can lookup its state later. For example if I turn a light on I save the state "light" : "ON" - but I don't think the JSON object is actually what turns the light on. It's just a way to record having done so.